# How do I make two mocks on one class in mockery?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, phpunit, mockery

I'm making unit tests using PHP(7.3), Laravel(7.6) & Mockery(1.3).
I need to make 2 mocks on 1 class(an eloquent model).
Does anyone have an idea?

Here is the production code.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'first_name'=>'required',
        'last_name'=>'required',
        'email'=>'required'
    ]);
    $contact = Contact::find($id);
    $contact->first_name =  $request->get('first_name');
    $contact->last_name = $request->get('last_name');
    $contact->email = $request->get('email');
    $contact->job_title = $request->get('job_title');
    $contact->city = $request->get('city');
    $contact->country = $request->get('country');
    $contact->save();
    return redirect('/contacts')->with('success', 'Contact updated!');
}
```

Here is the test code.
As for "Contact::find()", I successfully made a mock by (A) below.
But line(B) causes an error though I tried to make a mock for (C) below.

```
public function testUpdateNormal()
{
    //(A)
    $this->mock = M::mock('alias:App\Contact')->makePartial();
    //(B)
    //$this->mockInstance = Mockery::mock('overload:App\Contact');

    $valuesToBeSent = array(
            'first_name'=>self::FIRST_NAME,
            'last_name'=>self::LAST_NAME,
            'email'=>self::EMAIL,
            'city'=>self::CITY,
            'country'=>self::COUNTRY,
            'job_title'=>self::JOB_TITLE);

    //Posted values should be passed to this method as an argument.
    $this->mock->shouldReceive('find')->once()->with(self::ID)->andReturnUsing(function(){
            echo PHP_EOL . 'The mock was called in testUpdateNormal().' . PHP_EOL;
            //(C) I want to replace this instance with a mock.
            $newContact = new Contact();
            return $newContact;
    });

    $putTo = '/contacts/' . self::ID;
    $response = $this->put($putTo, $valuesToBeSent);
    $response->assertRedirect('/contacts');
    $this->assertEquals('Contact updated!', session('success'));

    //Check all values output in the page.
    $response->assertSee(self::FIRST_NAME);
    $response->assertSee(self::LAST_NAME);
    $response->assertSee(self::EMAIL);
    $response->assertSee(self::CITY);
    $response->assertSee(self::COUNTRY);
    $response->assertSee(self::JOB_TITLE);

    //Check header items in the page.
    $response->assertSee('First Name:');
    $response->assertSee('Last Name:');
    $response->assertSee('Email:');
    $response->assertSee('City:');
    $response->assertSee('Country:');
    $response->assertSee('Job Title:');
}
```

Comment: I came up with a solution, so I'll decline this post later. At the part of (C), I wrote like this `$this->mock->shouldReceive('save')->once();`, it seems to work.